# Vue: add focus on an input when changing a property in the pinia store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, focus, store, pinia

I have a component  that on click calls a function that does things in the store:

```
<button @click="this.store.foo()"></button>
```

And in the store I change this property:

```
state: () => ({
 focusIn: false,
}),
actions: {
 foo() {
   this.focusIn = true;
 }
}
```

Now how do I make sure that when I change this *focusIn* property in the store, it sets the focus to an input in a component other than MyComponent?

Comment: focusIn is a wrong direction because you can set it to true only once.

Answer (score -1):

you can add a templete ref on the button and use it to trigger the focus() function.

```
<template>
   <button ref="button" @click="this.store.foo(button)">Button</button>
</template>

<script setup>
const button = ref()
</script>
```

And in your pinia store

```
state: () => ({
 focusIn: false,
}),
actions: {
 foo(buttonRef) {
   this.focusIn = true;
   buttonRef.focus()
 }
}
```

Comment: But the ref() I want to trigger is not in the same component...the button is in one component and the input I want to make focus in is in another component

Comment: @Luca you can save the ref of the input in the store, and then when the button has been clicked you can invoke the focus method

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

1. add "ref" to your input:

```
    <template> <input ref="my_template_input"> </template>
```

2. make it focus when you need:

```
    this.$refs.my_template_input.focus();
```

Comment: Okay this thing I've already done elsewhere and it's fine, the problem this time is that it has to be triggered by a click that happens in another component. 
The click of that component calls a method that is in a store